# HTML, SVG - Clip path of external SVG not working

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have an externally defined group of SVGs:

*svgs.svg*

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        ... other SVGs ...

        <clipPath id="clip" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
            <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
        </clipPath>

        <symbol id="star" viewBox="0 0 256 244" clip-path="url(#clip)">
            <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
        </symbol>

        ... other SVGs ...
    </defs>
</svg>
```

And then include it into the HTLM with a `use` element:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 244">
    <use xlink:href="/images/svgs.svg#star"></use>
</svg>
```

But the clip path isn't working. I am adding a stroke to the SVG via CSS:

```
svg {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #F4C92D;
    stroke-width: 25%;
}
```

But the stroke is displaying outside of the polygon, which *should* be clipped.

This works fine, when the SVG is defined at the top of the HTML doc...

**[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/23eqkgL2/)**

... but no dice when externally defined.

Adding the clip-path via CSS has no effect:

```
svg {
    clip-path: url('/images/svgs.svg#clip');
    ...
}
```

The desired effect is for the stroke on the SVG to only appear inside of the defined polygon (like in the linked fiddle).

**Edit #1**

It also *does not* work, when adding the clip-path to the HTML element:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 244" clip-path="url(/images/svgs.svg#clip)">
    <use xlink:href="/images/svgs.svg#star"></use>
</svg>
```

BUT... it *does* work, when the clip-path is defined at the top of the HTML page (opposed to externally):

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>

    <svg style="width: 0; height: 0;">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip" viewBox="0 0 256 244">
                <polygon points="128 0 168.79 78.61 256 93.2 194 156.37 207.11 244 128 204.43 48.89 244 62 156.37 0 93.2 87.21 78.61 128 0"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>

    ... other markup ...

    <svg viewBox="0 0 256 244" clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <use xlink:href="/images/svgs.svg#star"></use>
    </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

... so, I'm unsure why it isn't working when defined externally. I also tried defining the clip-path in its own SVG file, with no luck.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure what you mean. There is an SVG file `svgs.svg`, an HTML file `index.html` and a linked CSS file `styles.css`. The CSS rules are all defined within the external CSS file. The fill and stroke work fine, it's the `clip-path` that isn't working.

Comment: What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: @RobertLongson Safari and Chrome both

Comment: And when you try Firefox...

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212

Comment: Safari is also a webkit browser, so maybe it's just a bug. Didn't test in FF yet, and already made changes to hack it together for now (using fix in **Edit #1**). I'll look into it further if anybody else comes up with a fix